# Text escaped when I want it to show up as html in Flask/jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, flask

I pull a feed from rss and store the data in a appengine db.  The rss feed content includes the entire html.  So I have this python code:

```
@app.route("/rssRead")
def pullRss():
    feedItem = db.getFeedItemByName(request.args.get('title',None), request.args.get('key',None))
    return render_template("rss.html", data= Markup(feedItem.html).unescape())
```

And my html template looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
{{ data }}
{% endblock %}
```

So when I view the page I have the actual html markup being displayed, how do I unescape the html data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `data=Markup(feedItem.html).unescape()`, you should be using `data=Markup(feedItem.html)`. That will do the right thing and keep your template clean.

Calling unescape() here is pointless (unless feeditem.html contains pre-escaped html, which it probably doesn't). More importantly, using unescape() here produces a string/unicode object instead of a Markup object, which keeps Jinja2 from recognizing that the field contains html that needs escaping. This defeats Jinja2's automatic escaping ability (that's the purpose of the Markup class!) I also forces your future template maintainers to remember that this field requires manual escaping, which clutters the template code with extra calls.

Answer (score 115):

This should work too.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
{{ data|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just to say thanks as well, this "|safe" portion works like magic, simple and awesome! :)

Comment: It produces the desired output, but it also hides an unnecessary unescape() call in the python code, leaves the python code in a state where it's failing to correctly represent what it's passing to Jinja, pushes onto the template maintainer the responsibility of knowing that `data` contains markup even though it isn't represented as such, and clutters up the template with an unnecessary `|safe` call. Not quite ideal.

Comment: This answer is much more polyvalent - had the same problem on Django and this solved it.

Comment: A band-aid is polyvalent, too, but it's still better not to cut yourself in the first place.