# passing string with html tags to html from python

Tags: python, html, flask-bootstrap

I have a result list which I am passing from python to my html document

like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

render_template('search.html', results=result)
```

*result* is a list of lists and it looks like this:

```
result= [['xxx', 'yyy', 'mmm', 'fff', '<b>...</b>vvv, <b>jj</b> <b>fkjfkj</b> ahbasb ashdkj akshdkj ajhsdkj ajksds <b>ah</b> gakshd<b>...</b>'], ['xxx', 'yyy', 'mmm', 'fff', '<b>...</b>vvv, <b>jj</b> <b>fkjfkj</b> ahbasb ashdkj akshdkj ajhsdkj ajksds <b>ah</b> gakshd<b>...</b>']]
```

The search.html code is the following:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %} Name of the page {% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <hr/>
<ul>
{% if results %}
    {% for hit in results %}
    <li> {{hit[0]}} | {{hit[1]}} | {{hit[2]}} | {{hit[3]}} | {{hit[4]}}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</ul>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When i run the application, the html file displays the bold tags as is instead of displaying bold text.

for example it displays this:

```
xxx | yyy | mmm | fff | <b>...</b>vvv, <b>jj</b> <b>fkjfkj</b> ahbasb ashdkj akshdkj ajhsdkj ajksds <b>ah</b> gakshd<b>...</b>
```

instead of:

```
xxx | yyy | mmm | fff | ...vvv, jj fkjfkj ahbasb ashdkj akshdkj ajhsdkj ajksds ah gakshd...
```

I know there is a simple solution to this. I just cant seem to see where i am going wrong.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572225/text-escaped-when-i-want-it-to-show-up-as-html-in-flask-jinja2 just try `hit[0]|safe`

Comment: Of course, I can use *safe*. working late ruins my head. that was simple and awesome. thanks!

Comment: Yes, that can happen when you work late :) good luck!