# Show content (include video and image) in Flask - Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

The site is able to display the whole content of the blog but not the video contents. When I try to post a new post including video. It's just show html script. Is there anyway to pass the whole html from python?

I'm using **post.content** to pass the post content to the html page. It works with text, but not image or video.

home.html:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username)}}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{ url_for('posts.post',post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <div class="article-content"><{{ post.content }}></div>
</div>
```

Routes.py

```
def home():
   page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
   posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()) \
    .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
   return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfipL.png)

Comment: The content is rendered as text to prevent Javascript injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. Just use this:

```
{{ post.content|safe }}
```

Work like a charm.

Refer: [passing string with html tags to html from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754535/passing-string-with-html-tags-to-html-from-python)