# Interacting with ChartJS from Flask

Tags: python, flask, chart.js

I am getting really confused on what to do here. I have a python script that does some cool things and then should display those cool things via some charts.

The way I've seen it's done is via Flask and ChartJS, but every website that I've seen uses it to display static content, which, of course, is not what I need.

I've tried doing this with this template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script src="/static/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/chartjs/utils.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas{
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
    <button id="addDataset">Add Dataset</button>
    <button id="removeDataset">Remove Dataset</button>
    <button id="addData">Add Data</button>
    <button id="removeData">Remove Data</button>
    <script>
        var MONTHS =  [];
        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['1/05/19\n00:57', '1/05/19\n00:58', '1/05/19\n00:59', '1/05/19\n01:00', '1/05/19\n01:01', '1/05/19\n01:02', '1/05/19\n01:03'],

                {{ dataset }}

            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });

            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });

        var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
        document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var colorName = colorNames[config.data.datasets.length % colorNames.length];
            var newColor = window.chartColors[colorName];
            var newDataset = {
                label: 'Dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
                backgroundColor: newColor,
                borderColor: newColor,
                data: [],
                fill: false
            };

            for (var index = 0; index < config.data.labels.length; ++index) {
                newDataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
            }

            config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
            window.myLine.update();
        });

        document.getElementById('addData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (config.data.datasets.length > 0) {
                var month = MONTHS[1];
                config.data.labels.push(month);

                config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
                });

                window.myLine.update();
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('removeDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
            config.data.datasets.splice(0, 1);
            window.myLine.update();
        });

        document.getElementById('removeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            config.data.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

            config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data.pop();
            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This contains a lot of unused stuff (it was downloaded directly from the chart.js samples) and slightly altered by me (see `{{ dataset }}`)

And this is the python code I use to generate the `dataset` part:

```
def generate_dataset(self):
    data = 'datasets: ['

    for post_list_index, post in enumerate(self.post_list):
        data =  data + "{label: '" + post + "', backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red, borderColor: window.chartColors.red, data: ["
        for index, history in enumerate(self.submissions_score_history):
            score = history[post_list_index]
            if index < len(self.submissions_score_history) - 1:
                data = data + str(score) + ','
            else:
                data = data + str(score)
        data = data + '],fill: false,}'

        if post_list_index < len(self.post_list) - 1:
            data = data + ','
        else:
            pass
    data = data + ']'
    return data
```

Now, unfortunately, this doesnt render anything. I'm pretty sure that this is due to the `label: 'label';` being escaped to `&#39label&#39;`.

I've searched about this issue and apparently this javascript injection thing I'm attempting to do has been removed because it represents a security vulnerability.

This project is quite literally just a dashboard for another small python project that will be used by me only, so I was trying to build something quickly and easily, but this is turning out to be quite troublesome :/

Comment: Hello, I have been searching about this and found out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5584567/3376838) using `|safe` ,can you try it and see if it works, it may not be the best approach but since the dashboard is only used by you.